# How to group data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I want to group my data based `episodes.id_e` and `episodes.id_mp_e`.

when i run this code

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  link_relation, 
          episodes, 
          master_post 
   WHERE link_relation.id_mp_lr = master_post.id_mp 
     AND episodes.id_mp_e = master_post.id_mp 
     AND episodes.no_e = link_relation.no_e_lr 
    GROUP BY episodes.id_e 
    ORDER BY episodes.tanggal_e DESC`


The result what I am getting is :

id_mp_e       no_e         column_n
============  ===========  ===============
1             EP02         xxxxxxxxx
2             EP01         xxxxxxxxx
2             EP01         xxxxxxxxx
1             EP01         xxxxxxxxx
1             EP01         xxxxxxxxx
```

what i have to do to group `id_mp_e` and `no_e` to get result like this

```
id_mp_e       no_e         column_n
============  ===========  ===============
1             EP02         xxxxxxxxx
2             EP01         xxxxxxxxx
1             EP01         xxxxxxxxx
```

table above only show `id_mp_e` and `no_e` if they have different value.

Comment: `GROUP BY episodes.id_e` - I don't see an `id_e` column here. `ORDER BY episodes.tanggal_e` - I don't see an `tanggal_e` column neither.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i have somany column, i just show 3 column here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have grouped on the wrong column.  Where you have:

```
GROUP BY episodes.id_e
```

You should instead specify the columns you want to group by:

```
GROUP BY episodes.id_mp_e, episodes.no_e
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more field (`episodes.id_mp_e`) in the `GROUP BY` clause, using comma separated:

```
SELECT * FROM  link_relation, episodes, master_post 
WHERE link_relation.id_mp_lr = master_post.id_mp 
AND episodes.id_mp_e = master_post.id_mp 
AND episodes.no_e = link_relation.no_e_lr 
GROUP BY episodes.id_mp_e, episodes_no_e
ORDER BY episodes.tanggal_e DESC
```

Comment: @Jazuly check the edited query - can u create a sql fiddle ?